# Questions about a rather specific query on Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

```
SELECT 
    Account_Invoice.amount_untaxed
    ,right(Res_Partner.vat, length(Res_Partner.vat) - 2) AS RFC
FROM Account_Invoice
INNER JOIN Res_Partner ON Account_Invoice.partner_id = Res_Partner.id
INNER JOIN Account_Invoice_Tax ON Account_Invoice.id = Account_Invoice_Tax.invoice_id
WHERE account_invoice.journal_id = 2
    AND account_invoice.date_invoice >= '2013-01-01'
    AND account_invoice.date_invoice <= '2013-02-01'
    AND account_invoice.reconciled IS TRUE
    AND account_invoice_tax.account_id = 3237
    AND account_invoice.amount_tax >= 0;
```

This returns the values that are untaxed along with the company's unique code.

The thing is, some of these do not return a vat code because there are many lines for a value inside `account_invoice` some of which have a `partner_id` that links to `res_partner` in which the `vat` column is empty. some of those lines however DO link to a line in `res_partner` that DOES have the correct vat code, do you guys have any idea how I can "ignore" the lines that do not link to the correct vat code?

Comment: You mean add a condition `AND Res_partner.vat IS NOT NULL' ?

Comment: yyyyyyyyyyyyea...that could work >_>

Answer (score 1):

add a condition `AND Res_partner.vat IS NOT NULL'

The query will stop returning records where res_partner does not contain a vat value for.

I'm assuming that the invalid vat value is NULL